# How to show only first result from select?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to show **only first result from this select**, but cant figure out how to do it or what function should I use.

I have tried **rownum <= 1**, but it changed shown result.

```
select name || ' ' || surname as meno, role
from system_user
order by surname ASC
;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle, you need to use a subquery:

```
select su.*
from (select name || ' ' || surname as meno, role
      from system_user
      order by surname ASC
     ) su
where rownum = 1;
```

The most recent versions of Oracle (12C) make this simpler by supporting the ANSI standard `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` syntax:

```
select name || ' ' || surname as meno, role
from system_user
order by surname ASC
fetch first 1 row only;
```